# Convert to URL to ASCII

Tags: php, encoding, ascii

i'm trying to convert this url:

`http://example.com/Gênesis/141588.mp4?AccessKey=3334ee81-a1ee-4f91-8cb5e4edfe1d-9a66-4144&download`

to this one:

`http://example.com/G%C3%83%C2%AAnesis/161680.mp4?AccessKey=3334ee81-a1ee-4f91-8cb5e4edfe1d-9a66-4144&download`

I used this command to detect the enconding of the second url and it says that it is ASCII: `echo mb_detect_encoding($str);`

and then I tried to convert it to ASCII using this `mb_convert_encoding($str, "ASCII");`

but the url stays like this: `http://example.com/G?nesis/141588.mp4?AccessKey=3334ee81-a1ee-4f91-8cb5e4edfe1d-9a66-4144&download`

help.

Comment: Isn't it url-encoding that you need here?

Comment: _URL to ASCII_ -> if a char is `?` it's an unsupported characters -> `ê` is not an ASCII character... you probably want this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: 1. `mb_detect_encoding()` won't detect this encoding. 2. `mb_detect_encoding()` won't even reliably detect the encodings that it's supposed to. 3. The function you're looking for is [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), but also you can't just cram a URL into it, you need to parse the URL and encode the relevant portions _individually_, and then re-create the URL. 4. [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url).

Comment: One of the issues you might run into is that `http://example.com/Gênesis/etc` isn't even a valid URI, so you're not really encoding it to ASCII, you're attempting to repair a broken one

Comment: Also `%C3%83%C2%AA` isn't `ê`, it's `Ãª`. This is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) caused by attempting to convert an ISO8859-1 string to UTF-8 that has already been converted. `ê` is `%C3%AA`.