# Previous URL Encoding to UTF-8 in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: utf-8, urlencode, codeigniter-4

How can i **encode this**:
http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/signin?continue=http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/

**To this**:
http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/signin?continue=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fcodeigniter4%2F

And do also help to **decode this**:
http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/signin?continue=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fcodeigniter4%2F

**To this**:
http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/signin?continue=http://localhost:8080/codeigniter4/

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909615/convert-to-url-to-ascii)

Answer (score 0):

Use **urlencode()** to **encode** the URL and **urldecode()** to **decode** the URL.